# How to apply diffeernt materials to different faces created using extrude tool

Tags: edit-mode

I have done this before to mesh models NOT created with the extrude tool but cannot work out how to apply a different material to some selected faces only.   I created my very simple SHED mesh object starting with a cube and then bisecting and extruding to create a roof which overhangs the 'shed' (see image below). I have applied a COLOR material (not the material I will ultimately use but this is an example) to the whole of the mesh object. Now I want to apply a different color to the 'fascia boards' so in edit mode I select all the faces and regardless of what I do the entire shed gets changed (in the image those meshes have been selected - show as gray). I can't even select only those parts of the 'shed' for a material without including those meshes for the 'fascia'.  Features such as a door will come later.

[image]

Comment: i'm not sure to understand, if you want to assign a different color to the sides of the roof you need to create a new material in the Material panel and assign it to the selected faces

Comment: @moonboots  Thanks but how do I do that? In edit mode I select a 'face' (ie one of the fascia) and then I selected the 'new material add a new material' but that didn't work for me. It still changes the material for the entire 'shed'. So I then tried removing the material from the shed (ie no material for any part of the 'shed' and then select just ONE FACE and then (material) NEW and the entire shed gets the material.

Comment: @moonboots Here is the 'shed' building mesh  (yes it is 'floating' in the air as I removed lots of other meshes for simplicity   [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=BRxjlb4M" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/BRxjlb4M/)

Answer (score 0):

Create the new material, keep it selected in the list, select the faces, click on the *Assign* button:

[image]

Comment: Thanks I have never needed to do that before. Something new I have now learned